# SQL adding numbers while handling nulls

Tags: sql

I have this statement here:

```
SELECT sum(table1.foo + table1.bar) AS Sum 
FROM table1
GROUP BY Fname;
```

When I try to add the numbers from foo and bar if one value from foo or bar is null it throws the numbers and gives me a different count sum

```
foo | bar
  6    4
  5    null
  9    1 
  2    1
  3    null
```

I want it to add all the numbers giving me a total of 31

but in this case it gives me a total of 23
Would love some help! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `coalesce()`:

```
SELECT sum(coalesce(table1.foo, 0) + coalesce(table1.bar, 0)) AS Sum 
FROM table1
GROUP BY Fname;
```

If you want the total, total on one row, remove the `group by`:

```
SELECT sum(coalesce(table1.foo, 0) + coalesce(table1.bar, 0)) AS Sum 
FROM table1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Any Number + NULL = NULL. You want to indicate to the engine that when it sees a NULL, it should treat that NULL value as 0.

```
SELECT sum(ISNULL(table1.foo, 0) + ISNULL(table1.bar,0)) AS Sum 
FROM table1
GROUP BY Fname;
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe you'll need to have SQL replace nulls with a zero using "ISNULL".

Try:
SELECT sum(ISNULL(fix_bat_sum.foo, 0) + ISNULL(fix_bat_sum.bar, 0) ) AS Sum

Comment: Isn't ISNULL sql server specific? Maybe COALESCE would be better idea.